# Call update stored procedure with parameter list using Enterprise library 5.0?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, enterprise-library

I have the following stored procedure "ResponseTracking_Put_Request" with 15 parameters. Is it possible to pass a parameter list for ExecuteNonQuery command?

Instead of repeating ".AddInParamter" 15 times :

```
SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(_connectionString);
DbCommand dbc = db.GetStoredProcCommand("ResponseTracking_Put_Request");
db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@requestId", DbType.Int32, requestId);
...
...
db.AddInParameter(dbc, "@description", DbType.String, description);
db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748700%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) overload that takes a stored procedure name and an array of objects.  The objects will be used as parameters to the stored procedure.

```
SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(_connectionString);
db.ExecuteNonQuery("ResponseTracking_Put_Request", requestId, description);
```

Or alternately:

```
List<object> parameters = new List<object>() { "123", "234", 99 }; 
db.ExecuteNonQuery("ResponseTracking_Put_Request", parameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: If I had 10 paramters, is there a cleaner way instead of overloading it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are after; you don't want to call AddParameter and you don't want to pass in the actual variables (which you seem to already have from your example).  Do you want to pass an array in? You can do that: `List<object> parameters = new List<object>() { "123", "234", 99 }; db.ExecuteNonQuery("ResponseTracking_Put_Request", parameters.ToArray());`

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted...parameter array example. Thanks Tuzo, you are awesome!